# Using std::unique_ptr on Qt

Tags: c++, qt

For so long i've been programming with the old C++, as me and my team never decided to upgrade to modern programming practices (i admit, part of it was my fault too), so lately i have been studying C++11, C++14, C++17 so i can get the hang of it, and the first thing i came across was std::unique_ptr, which in my opinion is amazing to use, but im still confused about using it with Qt, because i've read that in Qt if i create a QObject thats a child of another QObject, if the parent is removed, than the child will be removed as well, and that using std::unique_ptr might cause double deletion.
So i was wondering, is this correct:

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QSqlDatabase p_AppDB;
    QSqlQueryModel *p_QueryModel;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

#include "Dialog.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    p_AppDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE" , "test"); // Set Database connection driver + name
    p_AppDB.setDatabaseName("AppDB.db"); // Set SQLite database file name
    if(!p_AppDB.open()) // Open database and check if connection failed
    {
        qDebug() << "ERR: " << p_AppDB.lastError().text(); // Print out an error message
    }

    p_QueryModel = new QSqlQueryModel(this); // How do i avoid using 'new' here ?

    QSqlQuery _Query(QSqlDatabase::database("test")); // Create a new QSqlQuery
    _Query.prepare("SELECT * FROM Users"); // Prepare a simple query to select everything from the table 'user'
    if(!_Query.exec()) // Execute query and check if the execution failed
    {
        qDebug() << _Query.lastError().text(); // Print out an error message
        return; // Return if the execution failed
    }
    p_QueryModel->setQuery(_Query); // Set the QSqlQuery with its data to the QSqlQueryModel we created
    ui->View_TableView->setModel(p_QueryModel); // Set the QSqlQueryModel with its data to the TableView

    // TEST
    auto dlg = std::make_unique<Dialog>(); // Create a new Dialog
    dlg->exec(); // Execute (Display) the dialog
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    p_AppDB.close(); // Close the database connection
    delete ui;
}
```

How do i use std::unique_ptr when creating a QWidget for example or anything else instead of using the old: QWidget *w = new QWidget(this);

Im aware that there could be some errors because i havent programmed in quite a while and im now getting back to C++ and Qt again, but i hope if there are any other mistakes that you can point them out.

Thank you

Comment: A small remark. Take a look at `QPointer` class. It will be nulled automatically when object is destroyed. It may be useful to debug all pointer-based magic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't -- the QWidget parent/child ownership scheme and smart-pointers aren't interoperable.  You are correct that trying to control them with smart-pointers will often lead to double-delete problems.

In some cases you can do something like `std::unique_ptr<QWidget> ptr(new QWidget);`, and the `QWidget` object will get deleted when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope, as expected -- but a lot of the functionality in Qt is based on traversing the object-tree that is assembled when you make various `QWidget`'s to be children of other `QWidget`'s, so managing a widget via a smart-pointer is only practical if that widget will never need to be a child of any other widget.

So:  When in Qt-land, do as the Qt API does, and use the traditional parent-child-ownership approach where appropriate.

Comment: Yeah thats what i was looking for, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 12):

You should not use pass pointers owned by a `unique_ptr` directly into Qt.

I.e. this would be dangerous:

```
std::unique_ptr<QLabel> label = std::make_unique<QLabel>();
layout->addWidget(label.get());
```

`addWidget` will pass ownership of your pointer to the Qt layout and you will get double deletes as `unique_ptr::get()` does not relinquish ownership. The same goes for adding widgets to other widgets and the like. Qt assumes that it is taking ownership.

However, it may make sense to use `unique_ptr` temporarily to avoid leaking inside your method. I.e:

```
std::unique_ptr<QLabel> label = std::make_unique<QLabel>();
layout->addWidget(label.release());
```

The difference is the use of `release()` instead of `get()`. This will cause `unique_ptr` to relinquish ownership which in turn will be taken over by the Qt layout and you avoid a naked new in your application code, which could cause a leak if you somehow forget to assign it to a layout or a widget.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` with custom deleters.

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>


namespace qt {
namespace _details {
template<typename T>
struct q_deleter
{
    // T is not QThread
    template <typename Q = T,
             typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<QThread, Q>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    void operator()(T *ptr_)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<QObject, T>::value,
                      "stdx::qt::*_ptr<T>: T must be QObject or its children!");
        ptr_->deleteLater();
    }

    // T is QThread
    template <typename Q = T,
             typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<QThread, Q>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    void operator()(T *ptr_)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<QObject, T>::value,
                      "stdx::qt::*_ptr<T>: T must be QObject or its children!");
        ptr_->quit();
        ptr_->deleteLater();
    }
}; // struct q_deleter
} // namespace _details

template<typename T, typename D = _details::q_deleter<T>>
using unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, _details::q_deleter<T>>;

template <class T, typename D = _details::q_deleter<T>>
unique_ptr<T> make_unique() {
    return unique_ptr<T, D>(new T());
}

template <class T, typename D = _details::q_deleter<T>, class... Ts>
unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Ts&&... args) {
    return unique_ptr<T, D>(new T(std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
}


template<typename T>
using shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;

template <class T, typename D = _details::q_deleter<T>>
shared_ptr<T> make_shared() {
    return shared_ptr<T>(new T(), _details::q_deleter<T>());
}

template <class T, typename D = _details::q_deleter<T>, class... Ts>
shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Ts&&... args) {
    return shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Ts>(args)...), _details::q_deleter<T>());
}
} // namespace qt
```

With this header you can use smart pointers from standard library. But you cannot pass parent pointer(except `nullptr`) while constructing objects.
example usage:

```
auto qobj_ptr = qt::make_unique<QLabel>();
```